# Article writing: How to represent a matrix by its elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, article-writing

Intuitively I guess that parantheses with subscript and superscripts is a way of representing a matrix or an array by its elements, e.g.,

$$
A = (a_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^n
$$
(This is taken from [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function#In_analysis))

However, I can't use this representation in my papers because I am not sure and confident about it. Could you explain or give a reference site?

Comment: This notation is quite rare in my experience. You could say "$A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with entries $a_{ij}$" or $$A = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1n} \\ a_{21}&a_{22}&\cdots&a_{2n} \\ \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\ a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\cdots&a_{nn} \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: is your question answered?

Comment: I would use $a_{ij}$ or $a_{i,j}$.  The dimensions should be pretty clear from the context, although your notation would be fine too.